# Markers not placed on Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have two functions `initialize()` and `placeMarker()` now whats happening is that in the `initialize` method whenever the page loads it is called and it initializes the map then it sends a request to a php script which sends the longitude and latitude positions in response.

The response of the script is correct as I've checked it using the alertbox.

When I call the `placeMarker` function from outside of `$.each` it works.

But if I call it from inside of `$.each` it does not place the marker.

```
function initialize(latitude,longitude)
{
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    //Initial Map Variables
    var mymap={
            zoom:8,
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };  

        //Initialize Map
        map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mymap);

           //  placeMarker(latitude,longitude);
           //  placeMarker(latitude + 0.2,longitude + 0.2);     When these two are called it places the marker on the map

    $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "Profile_Control.php",
          data: "ajaxRequest=yes&id="+document.getElementById("compid").value,
          success:function(data){
             var parsedData= $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(parsedData,function(){
                placeMarker(this['lat'],this['lng']);           

        //not place the marker on the map.
            });
        }
        }); 
}


//Place the marker and update the array.
function placeMarker(latitude,longitude)
{
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position:myLatLng,
                }); 
}
```

Comment: Is there any error the browser given?

Comment: how to check that ? Browser is working normally.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, press Ctrl+Shift+J to open the console and see if there's errors there

Comment: yeah i get this error `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=src:apiv3,ts:1338119215974"`.

Comment: can you use `console.log` to log the value of `parsedData`?

Comment: the values are appearing correct I've used alertbox to check them and the alertbox is showing the correct results of longitude and latitude values

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$(parsedData).each(function(j) {
  placeMarker(parsedData[j]['lat'],parsedData[j]['long']);
});
```

Comment: Try `placeMarker(parsedData[j].lat,parsedData[j].long);` then. Also, which version of jQuery are you using?